# If a function returns new promise, does it need the async keyword?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a function that checks if an image exists, like this:

```
function getImage(source) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image()
    img.onload = () => resolve(img)
    img.onerror = reject
    img.src = source
  }
}
```

Should I write the function as:

```
async function getImage(source) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image()
    img.onload = () => resolve(img)
    img.onerror = reject
    img.src = source
  }
}
```

Does it make a difference in this particular case? Can somebody please explain?

The code will be used like this:

```
async function checkImage() {
  try {
    const img = await getImage('path-to-image')
    this.logoImg = img.src // does something with the image
  }
  catch(e) {
   this.logoImg = 'path-to-a-different-image' // does something else if the image is broken, etc.
  }
}
```

Never mind the "this.logoImg" part.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, if a function already explicitly returns a Promise, the `async` keyword will do nothing at all

Comment: IMO, there are three scenarios where you should use `async`: (1) you want to use `await` within the function. (2) You want whatever is returned from the function to be wrapped in a promise, for consistency, even if you return something other than a promise. (3) You want to ensure that any thrown errors are wrapped in a promise. Your example doesn't fit into any of these categories, so I would say you don't need `async`.

Answer (score 0):

No,
`async` is required for `functions` those are using `await` inside it.

`await` is used to avoid `.then`

Here if `getImage` returns `promise` only so no need to use `async`

```js
function getImage(source) { // This function returns promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//    ..doesn't have await..
  }
}
```

Here `async` is required because `usingGetImage()` using `await` inside it

```js
async function usingGetImage(){
const img = await getImage('my-image')
}
```

Hope this will answer your question :)